# Comparing each element in of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here's my problem:

> Write a method called `allLess` that accepts two arrays of integers and returns true if each element in the first array is less than the element at the same index in the second array. Your method should return false if the arrays are not the same length.

Here is my test data:

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,4}; 
int[] arr2 = {3}; 
int[] arr3 = {5,4,6}; 
int[] arr4 = {2,2,7}; 
int[] arr5 = {2,3,6,8}; 

System.out.println(allLess(arr1,arr2)); //should print false 
System.out.println(allLess(arr1,arr3)); //should print true 
System.out.println(allLess(arr1,arr4)); //should print false
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b){
    int len1=a.length;
    int len2=b.length;
    if(len1==len2){
        for(int i=0; i<len1;i++)
            if(a[i]<b[i])
                return true;
    }
    else if(len1 !=len2)
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

However, when I try `System.out.println(allLess(arr1,arr4));` it's  printing true.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux:  you should scan until you find a mismatch.  You're currently only looking for the first happy case.

The main part that you need to change is your conditional - flip its condition.

```
if(a[i] >= b[i]) {
    return false;
}
```

Be sure to change your last return to `true` as you've exhausted all negative conditions, and you're pretty much good to go.

There's more cleanup that should be done here, since we're looking at it.

First, **use braces everywhere.** Do so and your code will be a fair bit easier to follow.  You also won't run into bugs if you suddenly discover you need to add more to a conditional block without braces.

Next, you don't need to declare more variables for the length of the arrays - you only care about them in two spots.  Just reference `a.length` and `b.length` directly as it's not a method call; it's a field, which costs nothing to access.

Third, your `else if` condition is redundant; it should be an `else`.  Either the lengths of the arrays are equal or they're not.

Here's what it might look like overall:

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length == b.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Simplifications to this basic form exist.

---

If you were interested in a Java 8-centric approach, then you could consider this methodology with streams.  Essentially, we want to scan all of your elements, and reject the entire statement if the length of the arrays are not equal AND if the value in a<sub>i</sub> is not equal to b<sub>i</sub>.

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return a.length == b.length && IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                                            .allMatch(i -> a[i] < b[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 I personally don't necessarily agree with the "use braces everywhere" argument for experienced developers (that's what indentation is for), but for beginners it's a good idea. Coding style is a never ending debate however; it's the cause of most arguments when starting a new project.

Comment: @LINEMAN78:  It saves so much heartache, and one can't rely on indentation forever.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is returning early, you need to invert the logic and return:

```
            if(a[i]>=b[i])
                return false;
```

Comment: and I would need to change the last return to true, right?

Answer (score 0):

This code only compares the first two elements of the arrays. You could instead try the following:

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b){
int len1=a.length;
int len2=b.length;
if(len1==len2){
    for(int i=0; i<len1;i++)
        if(!(a[i]<b[i]))
            return false;
}
else if(len1 !=len2)
    return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: the `if` statement on the `else` is unnecessary. The optimizer should remove it, but I never count on that.